# Getting Redmine integrated with svn while running passenger as user www-data

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, phusion-passenger, redmine, www-data

I'm having some problems getting passenger and svn to work in Redmine.

## System

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Apache 2.2.22
- PassengerRuby 1.9.1
- Passenger 3.0.19

## Problem

When I let Passenger do it's normal user switching and run as www-data, svn integration doesn't work.
I have made sure to enter an absolute path to svn (/usr/bin/svn) in configuration.yml, but when I go to *Administration->Settings->Repositories* there is a red exclamation icon next to the command. Also, when I create a new project and try to create a repository I get this error message

> SCM command is not available. Please check settings on the
>   administration panel.

Now, if I instead let passenger run as my own user *myusername* svn works. This is not how it should be run though, as far as I know.

So my thinking is that is's a permission problem somewhere, but I just can't figure out where.

I have made sure that my self signed certificate is not causing problems by accepting it permanently while running svn as www-data like this:

```
sudo -u www-data -H svn --username mysvnusername info https://svn.mydomain.com/myrepo
```

This works correctly as far as I can see. It writes into */var/www/.subversion* and when I run it again I'm not asked about the certificate.

Here is the relevant output of *ps -ef*:

```
UID      PID   PPID   C STIME TTY      TIME     CMD
root     16151     1  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     16155 16151  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 PassengerWatchdog
root     16158 16155  0 14:41 ?        00:00:02 PassengerHelperAgent
root     16160 16158  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 Passenger spawn server
nobody   16165 16155  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 PassengerLoggingAgent
www-data 16205     1  0 14:41 ?        00:00:04 Rack: /var/www/redmine
www-data 16391 16151  0 14:52 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16418 16151  0 14:53 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16427 16151  0 14:53 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

To be clear here, the problem doesn't seem to be the actual connection to the svn server, but a problem with www-data running the actual svn command.

Where should I look? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this for now by adding a new system user and chown'ing the redmine application dir to the redmine user:

```
sudo adduser --system redmine  
sudo chown -R redmine:www-data /var/www/redmine
```

Now the Redmine application is running as user redmine and svn works. Maybe this is also the best solution with regards to security?